# Fixed Position Image That Keeps Exact Width + Height and Position

Tags: css, position

I am able to get this working to a certain degree, but not 100% the way I want. So if anyone can help me get this right it would be much appreciated.

I have a Wordpress website with a width of 1060px. I have created a DIV containing an image right before the `</body>` tag. I want this image to sit outside the left hand side of the site container. I have created this using the position: relative; CSS. However, what I want to do is have this elements to have the position: fixed; attribute so it will maintain its position on the screen when it is scrolled. Again I can create this within CSS. I can get everything looking the way I want on a 1920x1080 screen, but when I view it on a 2304x1440 screen, the image shifts it's position further away from the site container and the effect is lost.

Here is an example of the HTML and CSS I have used to get the effect looking right on a 1920x1080 screen;

HTML

```
<div class="left-container-wrapper">
<div class="left-container"><img src="image-url.jpg" width="100%"         /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-container-wrapper {
width: 50%; /* Get it to be half the screen width */
.left-container{
float: right; /* To force it to the right edge of the parent container     which is exactly half the screen width */
position: fixed;
left: 530px; /* Half the width of the site container */
}
```

What I am after is a way to keep an image stationary on the screen with a fixed position, that touches the edge of my site container on all screen sizes.

Can anyone suggest some CSS that will create the effect I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media to alter the body, adding an image, after the screen size reaches the full width of your page at 1080px. [Check out this jsFiddle for an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/ebcjrLfy/) Resize the lower right pane to see the effect.

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
body {
    background-image: url("https://s.w-x.co/twcn_TWC_FacebookVideo_825x130_opt3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
}

#content {
  margin: 50px 100px;
}
```